# How to format a cell with Google Sheets API v4 and Go?

Tags: go, google-sheets-api

I have to paste a date. For what I understood in the docs and SO is that I have to paste the days passed from 30 dec 1899 and format the cell as date.

Been the last hour looking for an example of formatting using the Go API client. Any example?

Thanks!

Edit: my code!

```
Google libs used:
"google.golang.org/api/option"
"google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
```

Function:

```
func googleAppend(bookID, sheet, tableCorner string, data []interface{}) {
    srv := connect(key)
    var vr sheets.ValueRange
    vr.Values = append(vr.Values, data)
    _, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(bookID,
        sheet+"!"+tableCorner, &vr).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet. %v", err)
    }
}
```

Tested with:

```
func Test_googleAppend(t *testing.T) {
    sample := []interface{}{"swwewewew", 3, 47120} <-- for what I understand, the destination of 3434343 should be formated to DATE.
    googleAppend("XXX", "SHEET", "A1", sample)
}
```

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you provide your current script? Because I would like to confirm the library you are using for using Sheets API. 2. Unfortunately, from `I have to paste the days passed from 30 dec 1899 and format the cell as date.`, I cannot understand about your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your goal, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike put some code! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. Can you provide the sample result you expect? Because I cannot understand about your expected result from `3434343`. Do you want to use this value as the serial number or the unix time? At Google Spreadsheet, the serial number is required when the date time is put.

Comment: @Tanaike added expected output. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the number format of the cell at the column "C".
- For example, you want to convert `47120` to `1/2/2029`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Golang.
- You have already been able to get and put values using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In order to change the cell format, it is required to use the method of batchUpdate in Sheets API. In your case, I would like to propose to change the number format using RepeatCellRequest in the batchUpdate method.

When this is reflected to your script, please modidfy as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please set `sheetId`.

```
func googleAppend(bookID, sheet, tableCorner string, data []interface{}) {
    srv := connect(key)
    var vr sheets.ValueRange
    vr.Values = append(vr.Values, data)
    _, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(bookID,
        sheet+"!"+tableCorner, &vr).ValueInputOption("RAW").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet. %v", err)
    }

    // I added below script.
    sheetId := 12345678  // Please set the sheet ID which is not Spreadsheet ID. Please be careful this.

    repeatCellRequest := &sheets.RepeatCellRequest{
        Fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
        Range: &sheets.GridRange{
            SheetId:          int64(sheetId),
            StartRowIndex:    0,
            StartColumnIndex: 2,
            EndColumnIndex:   3,
        },
        Cell: &sheets.CellData{
            UserEnteredFormat: &sheets.CellFormat{
                NumberFormat: &sheets.NumberFormat{
                    Pattern: "m/d/yyyy",
                    Type:    "DATE",
                },
            },
        },
    }
    requestBody := &sheets.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest{
        Requests: []*sheets.Request{&sheets.Request{
            RepeatCell: repeatCellRequest,
        }},
    }
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(bookID, requestBody).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)
}
```

- In this modification, after the values were put to the Spreadsheet using your script, the cell format of the column "C" is changed using the RepeatCellRequest in the batchUpdate method.

#### Note:

- In this case, when you run the script for changing the number format one time, you might not required to be run again. Because when the script is run, the number format of the column "C" is changed. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So about this, please modify the script for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: This will do! ありがとうございます !

Comment: @Gabriel A. Zorrilla Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. どういたしまして！